# Movie where scientists were doing experiments on prisoners and a surviving prisoner got god-like powers

Tags: story-identification, movie

There were some prisoners that these scientists were doing experiments on. All the other prisoners died except one. He had to be retaught how to read and write by the scientist lady. The prisoner started gaining god-like power and could read minds and I think I remember him scalping somebody. At the end he turns water into wine and the movie ends.

I believe it's newer, I saw it maybe 2014/2015. When it came out I started doing research about it looking for sequels; I found some behind the scenes discussions about the name. Originally it was supposed to be called "Prometheus" but then the other "Prometheus" movie came out shortly after and made them change their name.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Did you watch this on TV? Online? On physical media? If on TV, then in which country? And was it an English-language movie? Dubbed? Subtitled? Or did you just watch it in another language?

Answer (score 10):

Seems to be [The Frankenstein Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Frankenstein_Syndrome)

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEgCcbJcBcw)

They are running "Prometheus Project", there is a scalping scene on the youtube, and [turning water into wine trope](http://www.dvdbeaver.com/film3/dvd_reviews54/frankenstein_syndrome.htm).

[image]

> Researchers conduct secret and illegal experiments using stem cells.
> The researchers accidentally discover a serum derived from these stem
> cells capable of reviving dead cellular tissue. When a security guard,
> David Doyle, threatens to sue the research company and wants to leave
> the project, he is promptly murdered and used as a test subject.
>
> David returns to life but, in the style of The Reanimator, David is
> not the same man he once was. Not only is his personality and memory
> changed, but he is seen to acquired psychic and telekinetic powers, as
> well as increased strength and aggression. David begins to act out
> against the researchers, who all at once are his captors, murderers,
> and creators.

Comment: I'm interested to know if they actually had to change the name. There's lots of movies released with the same names, so much so that IMDB often lists them as Prometheus (I), Prometheus (II), etc.

Comment: @Valorum I searched IMDb for "Frankenstein Syndrome" and nothing matched in the auto-populated suggested results (which I've found to be extremely reliable). It wasn't until I clicked the search button to find a result for "The Prometheus Project a.k.a. Frankenstein Syndrome". I'm not knowledgeable enough with the workings of the industry to know exactly what that means, but it seems to me like it wasn't *changed*, per se, but released under multiple titles possibly.

Comment: @Daevin - Sounds like that might be worthy of its own question if you want to ask it