# Late 2000’s / early 2010’s sci-fi movie involving an experiment where water is turned into wine

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

I'm not too sure the exact details sadly. My biggest memory is that, at the end of the movie, the lead female researcher has her experiment turn water into wine in front of a priest and the movie ends.

The premise, I believe, would have to do with a team of researchers trying to revive a man. He basically comes back to life with the ability to read minds, and his powers grow and scare the team members, except for the lead researcher. She likes the subject and takes on a motherly role, if I’m not mistaken. The subject ends up killing the rest of the team, then the final scenes occurs at the end.

Comment: Hi. Was the movie set in something resembling the present day or a more obviously futuristic world?

Comment: Likely a dupe of [Movie where scientists were doing experiments on prisoners and a surviving prisoner got god-like powers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266749/movie-where-scientists-were-doing-experiments-on-prisoners-and-a-surviving-priso)

Answer (score 8):

Could this be [*The Frankenstein Syndrome*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1337686/) (AKA *The Prometheus Project*)?

> A group of researchers conducting illegal stem cell research discover
> a cell anomaly that has the potential to regenerate dead tissue.
> Unable to conduct legal human trials, the researchers turn to corpses
> to test their serum.
>
> [image]

[This review on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Frankenstein-Experiment-DVD/dp/B01M8PU8BU#:%7E:text=My%20trouble%20with%20the%20film%20arose%20when%20David%20evolved%20into%20some%20sort%20of%20murderous%20messiah%2C%20complete%20with%20the%20ability%20to%20turn%20water%20into%20wine.) mentions one of the (former) corpses turning water into wine.

> My trouble with the film arose when David evolved into some sort of
> murderous messiah, complete with the ability to turn water into wine.